# Adding String values from backed bean to inputtext field

Tags: jsf

I have a web program that must be able to do the following things:

The user will write a message that will be sent to many targets. In this case the user must be capable of inserting variable data amidst his message. For example:

Dear ${strName} happy birthday!

In this case the user would then have a inputtext field to write the message and a dropdown menu with the pre-determined strings (name, age, sex, etc.) which would then be passed with a command button to the inputtext field. How the program will then read these substrings and convert them to variable data is not important, I have that figured out.

My problem is I have no idea how to insert value from the dropdown into the inputtext form like that. Any Ideas? I will annex a mockup of how my form will look like.

[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AouAk.png)

XHTML:

```
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <label style="padding-top:5px">Dados variaveis:</label><br/>
            <p:selectOneMenu value ="#{sistemaDeAvisos.buscaAlvosDB.variavel}" onchange="submit()">
                <f:selectItems value="#{sistemaDeAvisos.buscaAlvosDB.alvosTestesDropdown}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:commandButton value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"  style="margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 5px">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="strMensagem">
                    Mensagem(*): 
                </label>
                <h:inputTextarea value="#{sistemaDeAvisos.mensagem.strMensagem}" id="strMensagem" style="width:100%;min-height:200px"/>     
            </div>
        </div>
```

Backing Bean

```
public class BuscaAlvosDB {

private EntityManager em = Conexao.getInstancia().getConexaoMysql();
private ArrayList<AlvoCampanhaBean> alvosCampanhaList = new ArrayList();
private String variavel;
private List <String> alvosTestesDropdown = new ArrayList();

public void carregaAlvos()  {

    //Dropdown Field List
    alvosTestesDropdown.add("strName");
    alvosTestesDropdown.add("strID");
    alvosTestesDropdown.add("strPhoneNumber");
    alvosTestesDropdown.add("strEmail");

    }
}
```

The method that handles the update

```
public void handleEvent(){
    
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(mensagem.getStrMensagem());
    strBuilder.append(variavel);
    mensagem.setStrMensagem(strBuilder.toString());
    System.out.println(mensagem.getStrMensagem());
    System.out.println(strBuilder.toString());
    
}
```

Comment: I need to write the string from the dropdown as a substring in the inputText field

Comment: @BalusC: I think OP wants to, client-side, do a string-insert at a certain position (at the cursor) in a textArea field. The text to be inserted needs to come from the dropdown

Comment: @Kukeltje exactly

Comment: Sorry if I made myself hard to understand

Comment: That sounds like a simple onchange event and then update the textarea with AJAX.

Comment: @JulianDavid thanks for your response! Could you please explain a little further?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4abr7jc5/2/ here is an example of what I want to do but with Jquery

Comment: @LuccasK maybe I could help you but I need to see your JSF code, to make me a closer idea to know what kind of solution will be better for you, so if you could update your question posting at least the select, the button and the textarea in your mockup image I will see how I could help you.

Comment: @JulianDavid ok, thanks, I'll be posting that then

Comment: @JulianDavid I think I posted all the relevant information. It's a rather large project

Comment: @LuccasK is it absolutely necessary to make it with a substring? I mean the textarea content could change in other ways. Maybe you could give me more context about why do you need to use a substring, and I will try to think another solution to help you.

Comment: Hi @JulianDavid if you have another sugestion i'd be glad to hear it! I just want the best and easiest way to make this idea work!

Comment: All I need is a way for the user to introduce variable data into his text. Since you cannot do that directly I thought the best way to go around it would be to replace "marked" substrings in the text by variables after the user inputs the text.

Comment: @LuccasK fine so I will post an answer that I thought for your problem. Check it out and if it doesn't work for you, I will try to think another solution.

Comment: @JulianDavid thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Just use the jsfiddle you already had and use a plain jquery change event on the PF selectOneMenu (or use pe:javascript from PrimeFaces extensions) to read the value from the select (stackoverlow Q/A available on how to do that)  and insert it at the possition like you already tried in the jsfiddle. No need for ajax, update etc that is in the given answer

Comment: @Kukeltje I became quite interested in the "pe:javascript" PF Extension but weirdly enough did not find anything about it on google. Could you provide more info if possible?

Comment: Ok, I found some stuff but still did not figure out how to use this extension. Do I just plain write the javascript inside the pe:javascript tags?

Comment: when I post "primefaces extensions pe:javascript" in goole. I get https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/clientBehaviours/javascriptBehaviour.jsf

Comment: You can also put the call to a more complext function in there. And keep in mind that the 'this' object can be very helpful since it refers to the selectOneMenu.

Answer (score 0):

According with the comments we had had you could wrap your JSF code in an independent `<h:form />` tag, and with AJAX send the form to your bean and then update the content of your textarea. This is what I thought:

```
    <h:form prependId="false" id="form">
        <h:selectOneMenu id="sel" label="Name: " value="#{testBean.selectValue}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Joe" itemValue="Joe" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Amy" itemValue="Amy" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <h:commandButton type="button" value="Submit" id="btn" action="#{testBean.updateTextarea}">
            <!-- This sends the form with the "onclick" event to the backing bean to update the bean attributes, and then it updates the textarea -->
            <f:ajax execute="@form" event="click" render="txt" />
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:inputTextarea value="#{testBean.textareaValue}" id="txt" />
    </h:form>
```

In your backing bean you could make a simple method that join the textarea message with the value choosed in the select. Something like this:

```
//. . . 
private String selectValue;
private String textareaValue;

// getter and setter

public void updateTextarea() {
    setTextareaValue("Dear " + getSelectValue() + " happy birthday!");
}
//. . .
```

Try it and please let me know if you need something else.

Comment: Using `prependId="false"` is a bad suggestion. And this solution is working on a fixed template and at a fixed position. Not a good solution in my upinion

Comment: I did it like that to simplify the answer, but my main idea was to use ajax to update the content of the textarea, putting the select value on it. If you could improve my answer, or suggest something better, I will appreciate it.

Comment: I had just tried kind of the same thing and it indeed worked! Thing is, I now need it to insert the selected value on the caret position. But you dont have to help me with that, you helped enough! Thanks!

Comment: I will update with a little snipet of what im doing. Edit: Updated!

Comment: @LuccasK I want to ask, the rest of the message inside the textarea is the same ever? (without taking into account the value chose in select), because I think you could define the message like `Dear _name_ happy birthday!` and then use something like `string.replace("_name_", getSelectValue())`.

Comment: The message is not constant! I wish it was as easy as setting up a pre-made message haha The program is actually a little complex. The user can start many types of message campaigns and each type will bring in different types of variable data that the user may want to place in his custom message

Comment: I see, well I will try to think a solution to help you.